# How to resolve conflict in git terminal?

Tags: git

There is a conflict while merging two branches in git, How do I resolve conflict in the terminal. But in this case i can resolve this problem in Netbeans IDE easily. But i cannot resolve this problem in termial.

Answer (score 4):

1. Edit files with conflicts
2. `git add` files with fixed conflicts
3. `git commit` to finish merge

Comment: HUGE part of point 1. is making sure that your code works after your edits. Maybe add "1a. Tests hell out of your code" :)

Comment: I'd just add that `git ls-files -u` or `git status -s` will show files with conflicts you haven't yet resolved (by adding the correct content).

Answer (score 1):

git add .

git commit -am "Place your comment"

Answer (score 1):

Set alias for git add and git commit in single commit

git config --global alias.ac '!git add -A && git commit'

Comment: Unless I'm suffering severe and undiagnosed caffeine deprivation, this will merely put the conflicted content into the commit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

git add.

git commit -m "Commit Message Here"

Answer (score -1):

Try this too.

```
git add * && git commit -am "Add your comment"

* for add all untraked files.
```

Comment: Before running git you need to resolve the conflict as mentioned by Ruslan Ostafiychuk.